# Check if input is a txt file in C

Tags: c, if-statement, input

I know this is a question that has been asked before but seeing as it didn't really receive an answer and I haven't been able to locate one anywhere else I figured I would ask it again.

Basically I have a program that **when passed a .txt file from standard input** it reads through it and replaces every numeric character with a `*`. Now I was wondering if there was a way to test if the file passed to it is a .txt. This is being done to ensure that the output result is actually usable, if someone were to pass it a .odt  or .doc it doesn't work, and I am just trying to prevent that step from happening.

```
if( file is a .txt file)
{
    run program
}
else
{
    print error message and exit
}
```

Essentially I am looking for what I should put in the if statement. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: A text file... as opposed to what? Do you just care about the extension?

Comment: Basically to make sure that it is a .txt file and that no one tries to pass it something weird like .odt as that causes issues.

Comment: Do you wont to check in c if you can write that file?

Comment: @ChrisBeck Someone gave already an Answer from there (possible the Author of one Answer) and he got a DownVote. How could possible help your link ?

Comment: A combination of [`popen(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/) and [`file(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/file/) ?

Comment: Well we can't see the comments that were exchanged on the deleted answer now. But the question that I linked, to POSIX api, is indeed relevant. POSIX has a concept of "text file" and "printable file" and its api exposes functions to determine this, so it might be a simple way to help the OP.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: No, it's not a duplicate. `stat` can only tell regular files from other things that exist in the file system (e.g. directories, named pipes, symbolic links, etc.). It does nothing to check file extensions or file contents.

Comment: You can try ["libmagic"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic), the underlying library used by the `file(1)` command.

Comment: when you say text, does that include UNICODE as well ?

Comment: To identify any portion of the input as numeric—or anything at all, really—you have to know the encoding or that the encoding is the default or the encoding has to be discoverable from within the stream (e.g., xml charset). So, that's a start: Can the input byte stream be decoded by that encoding?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for a `.txt` extension, that's not so bad. Verify the filename passed is 4 characters or longer (if not, it's too short to have that extension), then do a `strcmp` (or `stricmp` to allow `*.TXT`, `*.tXT` etc., since Windows isn't case sensitive about this stuff) between the last four characters of the filename and `".txt"`. Note: On Windows, there is a [`PathFindExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that can do the heavy lifting of finding the beginning of the extension for a file for you.

If you're trying to verify the contents are text, that's a much harder problem. It all depends on what you mean by "text". There is no single way to represent text; you can often recognize UTF-16/UTF-32 text (and occasionally, UTF-8 text) cheaply by checking for a `BOM` ([Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the beginning of the file. But ASCII text doesn't have markers like that (and arbitrary binary data could have the BOM by coincidence); for ASCII you'd be stuck with heuristics, e.g. Are all the bytes in the file `< 128` (interpreting bytes as `unsigned char`), possibly with additional checks to assume some ASCII non-printable characters mean "not really text". And if it's an ASCII superset, then all byte values are legal, so the heuristics come down to recognizing language; not a trivial task. [`libmagic`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) can help on Linux, but it's still doing heuristic guessing when it comes to text.

Comment: in Linux a txt file has no .txt extension.

Comment: In Linux, there is no convention, so sometimes it has an extension, sometimes it doesn't. Linux is far less concerned with file name extensions than Windows is.

Comment: My hypothesis is that the determination of "file type", even if well-defined, should somehow be equivalent to the halting problem anyway.  So it can 1) either only be approximated by heuristics, or 2) be solved for a narrow, well-defined class of files (such as "a file that contains only ASCII printable characters).

Comment: And back to topic... the OP's input file is read from standard input, so there's no reliable, cross-platform way to determine the file name anyway.  The file name could be totally absent (it could be a pipe or anything).  So I guess the only way is to use heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

You can get fairly close using Linux `file` with `popen`. (of course it's not much help if you are running windows) While `file` isn't 100% bullet-proof on analyzing every type of file, it is exceptionally good at determining if a file contains nothing but ASCII text. Using `popen` to get the result of `file` and parsing the output, you can determine if `file` thinks the file contains only ASCII text. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PMAX 64

int chkinput (int nargs, int nreq, char **args);
int file_exists (char *f);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (chkinput (argc, 2, argv )) return 1; /* quick input check */

    char buf[PMAX] = {0};
    char cmd[PMAX] = {0};
    FILE *pp = NULL;

    /* create cmd string for popen */
    snprintf (cmd, PMAX, "%s %s", "file", argv[1]);

    /* call Linux 'file' on filename via popen to
       test whether the file is a text file */
    if ((pp = popen (cmd, "r"))) 
    {
        if (fgets (buf, PMAX, pp)) /* optional - strip newline */
        {
            pclose (pp);

            /* if ASCII found in buf - it's text */
            if (strstr (buf, "ASCII")) {
                printf ("\n %s -- %s\n", argv[1], strchr (buf, 'A'));
            }
            else    /* it's not text -- handle appropriately */
                printf ("\n %s -- not ASCII text\n\n", argv[1]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* quick hack to make sure you provided a valid
   filename as the first argument to the program */
int chkinput (int nargs, int nreq, char **args) 
{
    if (nargs < nreq || !file_exists (args[1])) { /* validate input */
        char *p = args[0];
        char *prg = p;
        while (*p) if (*p++ == '/') prg = p;
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input, usage: %s filename"
                " (must exist)\n", prg);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* check if file exists */
int file_exists (char *f) 
{
    errno = 0;
    int flags = O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL;
    int mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    int fd = open (f, flags, mode);

    if (fd < 0 && errno == EEXIST)
        return 1;
    else if (fd) {
        close (fd);
        unlink (f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pipe_chkfile ~/.bashrc

 /home/david/.bashrc -- ASCII text

$ ./bin/pipe_chkfile bin/pipe_chkfile

 bin/pipe_chkfile -- not ASCII text

$ ./bin/pipe_chkfile ~/Documents/beast-attack.pdf

 /home/david/Documents/beast-attack.pdf -- not ASCII text

$ ./bin/pipe_chkfile ~/Documents/nhs-20131009.odt

 /home/david/Documents/nhs-20131009.odt -- not ASCII text
```